# Android / Eclipse: How to trim the surround at a non-square png file?

Tags: android, eclipse, icons, png

I'd like to use a png icon in my app without surround (it's not a square). I made the file with transparent background with an image editor, after that I used "New -> Other -> Android Icon Set -> Launcher Icons" wizard in Eclipse. There is in "Configure Icon Set" panel an option, called "Trim Surrounding Blank Space", but it isn't useable (gray). How can i switch on this option? How can I switch off the background color in this wizard?

Comment: I have the exact question here! please, waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried this but I couldn't do it. Looking for it in google is a waste of time because there's nothing. My final solution was to use GIMP and then create 4 images, each one with my original image resized to fill the new image with the same proportions. After it I saved the images in their respective folders(inside res/drawable-). The size of them were:

1. 96x96 (xdpi)
2. 72x72(hdpi)
3. 48x48(mdpi)
4. 36x36(ldpi)